# Is it possible to use two heavyweight browser views with a layered pane using JxBrowser?

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I would like to display two overlapping browser views. As far as I can see the documentation suggests to use lightweight rendering mode. Mixing heavyweight and lightweight components is not recommended. However, what about several heavyweight browser views? Should it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't put the heavyweight `BrowserView` instances into a `JInternalFrame` or `JLayeredPane` where they might **overlap each other**, then you can put several heavyweight `BrowserView` instances on a window.